# It's possible to open current file, in another existent tab, splitted

Tags: vim

I have two file in two tab. I'll like to open, for example, the second one file, inside first one, but splitted. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To move / clone a file that is open in one tab to another, it's easiest to use the *buffer number*. The `:ls` command tells you this, or you could include it in the *statusline*.

Suppose you have buffer 1 in the first tab, and buffer 2 in the second. You can then clone buffer 2 to the first tab as a split via

```
:1tabnext | 2sbuffer
```